# Determining complete solution

Tags: linear-algebra

In [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/exams/MIT18_06S10_Final_Answers.pdf), problem 1D.

I find difficulties in trying to understand how we get the complete solution as:

$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + x_2\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + x_4\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $$

Using augmented matrix, I get:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Which has special solutions: $S_1 = x_2\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, S_2 = x_4\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and particular solution as $x_p = \begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}$

My $S_1$ is correct but somehow my $S_2$ and $x_p$ are different with the solution.

Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer is correct.

Just verify that $AS_2 = 0$ and $Ax_p=b$.

The representation of the solution space is not unique.

Remark:

- In fact $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2  & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ is not in the nullspace, it seems that they make a mistake in part $c$ and the error propagate to part $d$.
- The way $x_p$ is obtained in their solution is due to the statement $b$ is the sum of the columns of $A$, but your particular solution works too.